# modulus in BitVector

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bitvector

what is modulus in BitVector? I haven't found anything online to explain what it does. I tried to set it to a bigger number so it didn't mess with my calculations in GF $2^256$

```
class AXU():    
    def __init__(self, sec_param):
        self.sec_param = sec_param
    def getHash(self, t):
        modulus = BitVector.BitVector(bitstring='100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000') #choose something larger than 2^256
        a, b = random.randrange(self.sec_param) , random.randrange(self.sec_param)
        a_vector, b_vector  = BitVector.BitVector(intVal=a), BitVector.BitVector(intVal=b) 
        t_vector = BitVector.BitVector(textstring=t)
        return a_vector.gf_multiply_modular(t_vector, modulus, self.sec_param) ^ b_vector
```

In the documentation the modulus is

```
modulus = BitVector.BitVector( bitstring='100011011')  # AES modulus, from the documentation on BitVector
```

where the bitstring in decimals is 286.

Comment: That's not specific to BitVector is it? They're just doing modular arithmetic here

Comment: is it? so modulus should be bitstring='100011011'

Comment: So don't you mean to ask "what is the role of the modulus in AES"? Using BitVector in python is just some random implementation detail

Comment: I don't understand what it is and what it is doing............

Comment: how should I use it? how does it affect the computation? should i change it? can i change it? how is it being used.

Comment: It represents a polynomial used for computations in GF(2^8) in AES, see [FIPS-197](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf) section 4.2.